# HTML5 CSS (How to on hover image ignore transparent)

Tags: javascript, css, html, canvas

I have two images; one is on top of another:

HTML:

```
<img src='http://etc-mysitemyway.s3.amazonaws.com/icons/legacy-previews/icons-256/3d-transparent-glass-icons-media/001429-3d-transparent-glass-icon-media-a-media21-arrow-back.png' style='position: absolute; top: -50px; left: -70px'>
<img src='http://etc-mysitemyway.s3.amazonaws.com/icons/legacy-previews/icons-256/3d-transparent-glass-icons-transport-travel/036411-3d-transparent-glass-icon-transport-travel-anchor6-sc48.png' style='position: absolute; top: 20px; left: 20px'>
```

CSS:

```
img:hover {
    background: blue;  
}
```

[Example Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/0vc33e2n/)

I need mark triangle but marked anchor because mouse on anchor transparent place (how to ignore it..?)

Comment: It's against the rules to include a JSFiddle link and no code. Please don't attempt to bypass them by encoding your JSFiddle link. Questions should include the code necessary to reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, move your styles out of inline- then you can set the `z-index` of the triangle to be greater than that of the anchor, so it 'appears' on top, whilst using the `:hover` selector specifically linked to the triangle (remove `#triangle` if you want it to relate to both):

### [Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/swfour/0vc33e2n/1/)

```
#triangle {
    position: absolute;
    top: -50px;
    left: -70px;
    z-index:1;
}
#triangle:hover{
    background:blue;
}
#anchor {
    position: absolute;
    top: 20px;
    left: 20px;
    z-index:0;
}
```

Comment: Add a hover selector for the anchor then, change '#triangle:hover' to '#anchor:hover, #triangle:hover'

Comment: Alternatively, to do both at once, change '#triangle:hover' to ' #triangle:hover, #triangle:hover + #anchor'